# How to get library installation path

Tags: adb, internal-storage, installation

Some Android apps require libraries to be linked against by specifying `<uses-library>` in their Manifest (in the `application` element):

```
<uses-library android:name="com.example.customlib" android:required="true" />
```

It is possible to list the installed libraries on the device by running the following command:

```
$ adb shell cmd package list libraries                                                                                                                                                  1 ⨯
library:android.ext.services
library:android.ext.shared
library:android.hidl.base-V1.0-java
library:android.hidl.manager-V1.0-java
library:com.android.future.usb.accessory
library:com.android.location.provider
library:com.android.media.remotedisplay
library:com.google.android.gms
library:com.google.android.trichromelibrary
library:javax.obex
library:org.apache.http.legacy
library:com.example.customlib
...
```

Where are these libraries installed? Is there a command similar to `adb shell pm path com.exaple.packagename` that would return the path of `com.example.customlib`? When I tried `pm path`, it does not return anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the libraries you search can be found in `/system/framework`

Example output form an Android 10 device:

```
    3621 2009-01-01 01:00 CustomPropInterface.jar
  193854 2009-01-01 01:00 OPCommonTelephony.jar
   21325 2009-01-01 01:00 am.jar
   13122 2009-01-01 01:00 android.hidl.base-V1.0-java.jar
   31354 2009-01-01 01:00 android.hidl.manager-V1.0-java.jar
   33410 2009-01-01 01:00 android.test.base.jar
   57302 2009-01-01 01:00 android.test.mock.jar
  106118 2009-01-01 01:00 android.test.runner.jar
    5693 2009-01-01 01:00 appwidget.jar
   31002 2009-01-01 01:00 bmgr.jar
    7445 2009-01-01 01:00 bu.jar
    5310 2009-01-01 01:00 com.android.future.usb.accessory.jar
   20050 2009-01-01 01:00 com.android.location.provider.jar
    9230 2009-01-01 01:00 com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar
    2906 2009-01-01 01:00 com.android.mediadrm.signer.jar
    7954 2009-01-01 01:00 com.android.nfc_extras.jar
   19389 2009-01-01 01:00 content.jar
    9193 2009-01-01 01:00 dpm.jar
   99829 2009-01-01 01:00 duraspeed.jar
   38582 2009-01-01 01:00 ethernet-service.jar
 3007999 2009-01-01 01:00 ext.jar
27047266 2009-01-01 01:00 framework.jar
   17217 2009-01-01 01:00 hid.jar
  153906 2009-01-01 01:00 ims-common.jar
   13573 2009-01-01 01:00 input.jar
   54682 2009-01-01 01:00 javax.obex.jar
    3721 2009-01-01 01:00 locksettings.jar
   79905 2009-01-01 01:00 log-handler.jar
   16086 2009-01-01 01:00 media.jar
  114510 2009-01-01 01:00 mediatek-common.jar
   99278 2009-01-01 01:00 mediatek-cta.jar
  189961 2009-01-01 01:00 mediatek-framework-net.jar
  405350 2009-01-01 01:00 mediatek-framework.jar
  107978 2009-01-01 01:00 mediatek-ims-base.jar
   73974 2009-01-01 01:00 mediatek-ims-common.jar
   12061 2009-01-01 01:00 mediatek-ims-extension-plugin.jar
 2506910 2009-01-01 01:00 mediatek-ims-legacy.jar
  483881 2009-01-01 01:00 mediatek-ims-wwop-common.jar
  230333 2009-01-01 01:00 mediatek-services.jar
   49334 2009-01-01 01:00 mediatek-telecom-common.jar
  361002 2009-01-01 01:00 mediatek-telephony-base.jar
 2762490 2009-01-01 01:00 mediatek-telephony-common.jar
 1580981 2009-01-01 01:00 mediatek-wfo-legacy.jar
  114753 2009-01-01 01:00 monkey.jar
    3937 2009-01-01 01:00 mtk-wifi-service.jar
  491074 2009-01-01 01:00 org.apache.http.legacy.jar
   12445 2009-01-01 01:00 requestsync.jar
   10205 2009-01-01 01:00 sm.jar
   13273 2009-01-01 01:00 svc.jar
   13145 2009-01-01 01:00 telecom.jar
 2865674 2009-01-01 01:00 telephony-common.jar
  363793 2009-01-01 01:00 uiautomator.jar
   99817 2009-01-01 01:00 via-plugin.jar
  157682 2009-01-01 01:00 voip-common.jar
    4437 2009-01-01 01:00 vr.jar
 3391985 2009-01-01 01:00 wifi-service.jar
```